# Firestore: How to get all documents where field is in array

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

Trying to figure out if what I want to do is possible with firestore. I'd like to search a collection where a field value is in an array of arbitrary size. I'm not too sure if this is possible or how to best restructure the data for this use case.

For example if I had a collection of posts with a field "subject", how could I select all posts with subject in ["science, "math", "english" ...] and then order it by created date and limit it to a certain number.

Is this possible to do with firestore?

I'm not sure if it would make sense to run a seperate query with a where clause for each subject as I'd like to limit the posts and order them by created date, but perhaps there's a way that I haven't considered.

Thanks!

Comment: So you basically say that, if you have three documents, and the first one has the value of "subject" set to "science", the second one "math", and the third one "english", when you perform the query, you want to get all three documents, right?

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo, that’s correct! Is there any way to efficiently retrieve all those documents? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the [`array-contains` clause](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) of Firestore queries, which can be used to return documents where an array field contains the complete, exact value that you specify in the query. See the link for example in all supported languages.

If you want to match an array field against a list of value in your code, you can use an [`array-contains-any` clause](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any).

I you want to match a single-value field against a list of values in your code, that'd be an [`in` clause](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any).

Comment: Hi Frank, so I’ve looked at the array-contains clause but I’m not sure if it’s the correct one I want. I’m querying for  all documents where a key has a value that matches one in the query array. So for example the three documents may have different “subject” values and I want to get all queries where the value is in some array I pass to the query. For example

Comment: Hey, puf. The OP is looking for the `array-in` operator rather than `array-contains`. Please check the comments above.

Comment: @Alex: that'd be an [`array-contains-any` clause](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) wouldn't it? --- @Julian: if it's a single-value field, that'd be an [`in` clause](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) I think. --- I updated my answer to mention both, and also when to use them.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen thanks so much for the reply and the effort. I believe the “in” clause would work, however I noticed that it has a limit of up to 10 values. For my use case the array could be arbitrarily long (but probably around 20-30 items). I wonder if there’s any clean way to query the data as such. No worries if there isn’t I think for my use case it would also be possible to aggregate the data I need separately in a cloud function.

Comment: As I understood from OP's last comment, the "subject" field is of type String and not array. So the `in` clause should work.